# KRS ekrs.ms.gov.pl get documents from requests

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I want get information about documents when  enter company id 0000000155

My pseudo code I did know where i should pass company id.

```
url = "https://ekrs.ms.gov.pl/rdf/pd/search_df"

payload={}
headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0',
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: I doubt request would be able to handle your requirement. Try using selenium or similar tools to get the data

Comment: I use selenium very slow execution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all- you forgot to close the string after the 'Accept' dictionary *value*. That is to say, your headers should look like this:

```py
headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0',
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
}
```

As for the payload, after checking the website you linked, I noticed that the ID is sent in the `unloggedForm:krs2` parameter. You can add this to the payload like so:

```py
payload={
    'unloggedForm:krs2': 0000000155
}
```

However, in reality, it's nearly impossible to scrape the website like so, because there is ReCaptcha built into the website. Your only options now are either to use Selenium and hope that ReCaptcha doesn't block you, or to somehow reverse engineer ReCaptcha (unlikely).